# How tuples are unpacked in matplotlib python while plotting subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

`fig,((ax1,ax2,ax3),(ax4,ax5,ax6),(ax7,ax8,ax9)) = plt.subplots(3,3,sharex=True,sharey=True)`

`lineardata=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])`

`ax5.plot(lineardata,'-')`

**I have learnt that "plt.subplot" function returns a tuple,but i am not able to understand how they are unpacked in the fig, ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4,ax5,ax6,ax7,ax8,ax9**

Comment: Please describe the question clearly. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Probably, you have to do more research on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to explain `how they are unpacked in the fig, ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4,ax5,ax6,ax7,ax8,ax9`, we start with a simple code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
```

Now we discover `ax` by using python console (python interpreter)

```
in[0]: ax
Out[0]: 
array([[<AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>],
       [<AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>],
       [<AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>]], dtype=object)
```

it returns an array of dimension 3 x 3:

then, we share a snippet of your code

```
((ax1,ax2,ax3),(ax4,ax5,ax6),(ax7,ax8,ax9)) = ax
```

or

```
(ax1,ax2,ax3),(ax4,ax5,ax6),(ax7,ax8,ax9) = ax
```

in turn, we want to explore, how the contents of ax are distributed over the object names you gave.

This is done by exploring the relations between the left and right side of `=` in the later code- and again by using python console:

```
In[1]: ax1==ax[0][0]
Out[1]: True
```

and so on with others

```
In[2]: ax2==ax[0][1]
Out[2]: True
In[3]: ax3==ax[0][2]
Out[3]: True
In[4]: ax4==ax[1][0]
Out[4]: True
In[5]: ax5==ax[1][1]
Out[5]: True
In[6]: ax6==ax[1][2]
Out[6]: True
In[7]: ax7==ax[2][0]
Out[7]: True
In[8]: ax8==ax[2][1]
Out[8]: True
In[9]: ax9==ax[2][2]
Out[9]: True
```

so we deduced that the mapping has done as if

```
array([[<AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>],
       [<AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>],
       [<AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>]], dtype=object)
=
array([[ax1, ax2, ax3],
       [ax4, ax5, ax6],
       [ax7, ax8, ax9]], dtype=object)
```

So the mapping relies on matching the sequence of the object you give with the sequences of objects in row one, row two until the last row.

we also deduce that mapping is done with the resulted array and is not a part of the `subplots` function itself.

finally, we should mention that the resultant array `ax` is a `numpy.ndarray`, even if you did not import the `numpy` it.

I hope the above illustration declare what you ask about

and waiting for your comment

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and explaining me very clear it was really helpful, now i am clear about it.
May i ask like the dimension 3 x 3 is also assigned to figure ?(fig,ax=plt.sub.......)

like ax has been assigned 3x3
and fig has also been assigned 3x3 right ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question in the comment well, but we could say that ax carry objects pointers to the actual objects that belong to figure, so figure surely has these objects - and if you use PyCharm, you can run your code in debug mode, step by step, and investigate the memory contents and the details of each object and variable.

Answer (score 0):

`matplotlib.pyplot.subplots` returns a tuple with an figure-object and an array of axis-objects:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig,axs = plt.subplots()
axs[0].plot(...)
```

as the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) state:

> Return values:
>
> fig = Figure
>
> ax = axes.Axes or array of Axes

Answer (score 0):

If you have greater that 2x2 subplots, it may be easier to collect all the axes and the unpack them:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3, sharex=True, sharey=True)

ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6, ax7, ax8, ax9 = axes.flatten()

ax1.plot(lineardata,'-')
```

or do it in a loop:

```
for ax in axes.flatten():
    ax.plot(lineardata,'-')
```